# restrict .bmp, .exe, .bat attachment types while uploading for an issue in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Is there anyway to restrict the attachments of types - .bat/.exe/.bmp, etc to be restricted while user trying to upload them in JIRA.

I tried using the Servlet-Filter plugin module in JIRA. But I am not able to get the URL at the time of uploading the attachment. Also I am trying to listen to the Attachment event for an issue.

Is there any other alternative of restricting these file types.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well there was an Attachment Filter available but I am not sure if it is still relevant - it actually seems that it is [no longer relevant](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-6931) also if I recall correctly it was for 
Confluence. So you're left with writing a custom plugin for this.

You could implement `com.atlassian.jira.issue.AttachmentManager`, the default implementation is `com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultAttachmentManager` and wrap it so that you check what's going on with the upload - filetype etc. But be sure to check the mime-type - not only the file name and/or extension. Check [this out](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/27836/restrict-attachment-based-on-file-type).